# How handle CORS issue in laravel with reactjs with ports

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am facing the CORS issue with api's from laravel to reactjs.

I am running laravel at 5555 port and reactjs is running on 3000.

I have a middleware to allow the origin of 'http://localhost:5555'. But it still gives me an error.

My middleware is below.

```
<?PHP
  namespace App\Http\Middleware;
  use Closure;

  class HandleCors {
    /**
      * Handle an incoming request.
      *
      * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
      * @param  \Closure  $next
      * @return mixed
      */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
      $allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:5555'];
      $origin = $request->server('HTTP_ORIGIN');

      if (in_array($origin, $allowedOrigins)) {
        return $next($request)
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin)
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Cache-Control'); //in case if you want all (*)
      }

      return $next($request);
    }
  }
```

This is the custom code I have not installed any package for CORS.
How do solve this issue?

this is the error>>

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5555/api/MethodName' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:5555' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

Comment: Please share the error message as well

Comment: What version of Laravel is this? Since version 7 Laravel ships with [a cors library](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) and includes some boilerplate code to use it, which makes setting up CORS easier.

Comment: I am using the 6.2 version of laravel. Yes, i know that laravel 7 has the cors library.

Comment: The CORS middleware array if I set to $origin = 'http://localhost:3000' which is react's URL t is working but when I put the $origin = 'http://localhost:5555' which is PHP's hostname it is not working still giving me the error.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?